# How to draw a circle whenever a circle is found by my webcam using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

So, this piece of code seems to find a circle using my webcam pretty easily. However, I'd like it to also draw a circle whenever one was found instead of simply closing the program. I tried to add a "cv2.circle(parameters...)" to the code but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np  
import sys  
color = (0,0,255)  
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
while(True):  
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),5)  
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10, minRadius = 1, maxRadius = 20)   
    if circles != None: print "Circle There !"  
    cv2.imshow('video',gray)  
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:# esc Key  
        break  
cap.release()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please use the button that looks like this: `{ }` to format as code when you write questions. You can also highlight the text and press control-k in most cases.

Comment: Your code those not show where you are doing the cv2.circle function... maybe you can put the whole code to see what could be wrong...

Comment: [This page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html) shows how to do basically what you want for a single image... see if you can duplicate it in video form.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to want to mess with the parameters in the cv2.HoughCircles function (you may even be able to delete some of the params entirely), but this should work.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  

while(True):  

    gray = cv2.medianBlur(cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),5)  
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10, param1=150,param2=40,minRadius=0,maxRadius=1000)

    if circles != None:
        for i in circles[0,:]:
            # draw the outer circle
            cv2.circle(cgray,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
            # draw the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(cgray,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

    cv2.imshow('video',cgray)  
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:# esc Key  
        break  

cap.release()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```